# create view on different databases on different hosts

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a view from tables from two different databases? Like:

```
creative view 'my_view' as
  select names as value
  from host_a.db_b.locations 
  union 
  select description as value 
  from host_b.db_b.items;
```

They currently are different database engines (MyISAM and InnoDB).

thx in advance

Comment: Why -1? Because this will work?

Comment: not sure about downvote. Haven't tried, hence the question. Google answers looked pretty out of date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to access the remote table [via the FEDERATED db engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html), then [create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) using your query.

However this is a rather messy way to solve the problem - particularly as (from your example query) your data is effectively sharded.

This structure won't allow updates/inserts on the view. Even for an [updatable/insertable view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html), my gut feeling is that you'll run into problems if you try to anything other than auto-commit transactions, particularly as you're mixing table types. I'd recommend looking at replication as a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: thx for response, I'm still thinking about how to do this. We currently have this view in the same database and it is working fine. Your idea of replicating just the view when / if that time comes seems like a goog idea.